# Understanding CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX when building LLVM

Tags: macos, cmake, llvm

I am following this [guide](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~bholt/posts/building-llvm.html) for building LLVM and wanted to confirm my understanding of this build option. My current path for my source is:

```
$HOME
|--Documents
|--...
|--Projects
|  |--llvm
|  |  |--source
|  |  |  |--#llvm source code
|  |  |--build
|  |  |  |--Release
|  |  |  |  |--performing cmake -G Ninja from this directory
```

Now my question is, for the `$prefix` variable, would that path be `~/Projects/llvm/build/Release`? Which will have it install everything to my working source for llvm rather than the installation native to OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directory `build/Release` accumulate files created on *build* stage (when you execute `ninja`).

At *install* stage (`ninja install`) some of these files will be copied into their *final location*, determined by `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable. Copied files themselves are sufficient for project (LLVM in you case) to work; so files from *source* and *build* trees can be safetly removed if you want to free space.

Usually, `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` determines root of the installed files, so all files will be installed under given directory. This directory is futher reffered in the guide as `LLVM_DIR`.

It is better to not use build directory and its subdirectories for `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, as this may cause copiing of overlapping files during *install*. In you case `~/Projects/llvm/install` is perfectly suited for being install prefix.